# Add Zoom Level to Map within TileLayer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, debugging

I used ArcGIS javascript API 3.0 version and I use Bing map. I need to be able to zoom to 22., 23., 24., .. levels. So I was added an addNumLevels function to Map;

```
 esri.Map.prototype.addNumLevels =function(num){

    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++ ){
        var ln = this.__tileInfo.lods.length;
        this.__tileInfo.lods[ln] = {};
        this.__tileInfo.lods[ln].level = ln;
        this.__tileInfo.lods[ln].resolution = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].resolution / 2;
        this.__tileInfo.lods[ln].startTileRow = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].startTileRow;
        this.__tileInfo.lods[ln].startTileCol = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].startTileCol;
        this.__tileInfo.lods[ln].endTileRow = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].endTileRow * 2;
        this.__tileInfo.lods[ln].endTileCol = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].endTileCol * 2;
    }
}
```

But I when I upgraded the ArcGIS js api to version 3.2, my addNumLevels function stopped working.
Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem for ArcGIS javascript API 3.3 version with this function;

```
esri.Map.prototype.addNumLevels = function(num) {
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
        var ln = this.__tileInfo.lods.length;
        var newLod = new esri.layers.LOD();
        newLod.level = ln;
        newLod.resolution = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].resolution / 2;
        newLod.startTileRow = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].startTileRow * 2;
        newLod.startTileCol = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].startTileCol * 2;
        newLod.endTileRow = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].endTileRow * 2;
        newLod.endTileCol = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1].endTileCol * 2;
        /* this control for ex apis*/
        if(this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1]._frameInfo) {
            newLod._frameInfo = new Array();
            newLod._frameInfo[0] = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1]._frameInfo[0] * 2;
            newLod._frameInfo[1] = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1]._frameInfo[1] * 2;
            newLod._frameInfo[2] = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1]._frameInfo[2] * 2;
            newLod._frameInfo[3] = this.__tileInfo.lods[ln-1]._frameInfo[3] * 2;
        }
        this.__tileInfo.lods[ln] = newLod;
    }
    /* They are new map params and we must set them*/
    this._params.lods = this.__tileInfo.lods;
    this._params.maxScale = this.__tileInfo.lods[this.__tileInfo.lods.length - 1].scale;
    this._params.maxZoom = this.__tileInfo.lods.length - 1;
};
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this but would you not do this through the use of [LOD](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/lod.htm) (Level of Detail) on the [map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/map.htm) options parameter? Sample [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/map_switch_layer_on_zoom.html)

Comment: Thanks but this sample a visibility control between ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer's levels. I can't zoom to level 20 or level 21. I have to go out of ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer's levels, because i have another map layer that is a ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer and i have to zoom to map about 100 scale.